# why jquery confirmation ins not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-confirm

am trying to get best confirmation why jquery is not working what went wrong  am not getting confirmation dailog box

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/trso8x65/

```
<html>
     <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.0.3/jquery-confirm.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.0.3/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>

      <button type="button" class="confirm">click me </button>
    <script>
      $.confirm({
        title: 'Confirm!',
        content: 'Simple confirm!',
        buttons: {
            confirm: function () {
                $.alert('Confirmed!');
            },
            cancel: function () {
                $.alert('Canceled!');
            },
            somethingElse: {
                text: 'Something else',
                btnClass: 'btn-primary',
                keys: ['enter', 'shift'],
                action: function(){
                    $.alert('Something else?');
                }
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What part of your code links the button with the action? (Also, the button code in your fiddle is different from the button shared here)

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should work basically

```
 <html>
 <head>
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.0.3/jquery-confirm.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.0.3/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="complexConfirm">Click me</button>


   <script>


   $("#complexConfirm").confirm({
    title: 'Confirm!',
    content: 'Simple confirm!',
    buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
            $.alert('Confirmed!');
        },
        cancel: function () {
            $.alert('Canceled!');
        },

    }
});

   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference from my answer? Was there any other issue present that we didn't spot?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing jQuery Library .

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It Must Be Very First Library Under Head Section .

Answer (score 0):

- List item your external urls were entered incorrectly

  - The jquery-confirm.min.js url is producing "404 Not Found".

    - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.0.3/jquery-confirm.min.jshttps://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.0.3/jquery-confirm.min.jshttps://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.0.3/jquery-confirm.min.js
  - It should be...

    - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.0.3/jquery-confirm.min.js
- you didn't have jquery selected in the javascript section of your

Comment: The answer wouldn't allow me to post the jsfiddle fork... here you go https://jsfiddle.net/cpardon/2hnpsmh4/ It works fine by simply updating the items I suggested above.

Comment: your fiddle working correct but modal should be open when i click on click me button

Comment: I believe my answer solved the question you posed here. If so, please check mark this as answered. As bonus, I'll have a look further into the click me button issue as well.

Comment: @jancypradeep your question stated "am not getting confirmation dailog box".. I fixed your jsfiddle in my forked version & the confirmation is opening correctly. Hence, your posed question is answered

Comment: Dont answer for the sake gaining points i am using this effective learning whenever anyone posted question you just answer with some more features or guide how to do that

Comment: Mate, you posed a question. Then followed it with further questions, once i was fixed I'd fixed the original problem. That said, I've fixed you CLICK issue. See my updated jsfiddle. I binded the confirm to the click event.

Comment: I did this by wrapping your $.confirm script inside of $('body').on('click', '#confirm', function() { **insert confirm script here ** });

Answer (score 0):

You possibly have other issues (as noted, you don't seem to be loading jQuery, on which [jQuery.confirm](https://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/) depends, and that should trigger a very clear error message in the JavaScript console) but the main problems is that you never link your button with the plug-in:

```
<button type="button" class="confirm">click me </button>
```

```js
$.confirm();
```

Right from the project page:

```
<a href="home" class="confirm">Go to home</a>
```

```js
$(".confirm").confirm();
```

In other words, you need to call the plugin on an jQuery object with a proper selection.